# Ingest CSV data with Auto Loader with Specific Delimiters / separator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I'm trying to load a several csv files with a complex separator("~|~")

The current code currently loads the csv files but is not identifying the correct columns because is using the separator (",").

I'm reading the documentation here https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader-csv.html but it doesn't say anything about it or at least I'm not able to see it

```
spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
  # The schema location directory keeps track of your data schema over time
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "<path-to-checkpoint>") \
  .load("<path-to-source-data>") \
  .writeStream \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "<path-to-checkpoint>") \
  .start("<path-to-target")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader-gen2.html#file-format-options) says:

> With Auto Loader you can ingest JSON, CSV, PARQUET, AVRO, TEXT, BINARYFILE, and ORC files. See [Format options](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html#format-options) for the options for these file formats.

So you can just use standard [options for CSV files](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html#csv-options) - you need the `delimiter` (or `sep`) option:

```py
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
  .option("delimiter", "~|~") \
  .schema(...) \
  .load(...)
```